# React Table outsourcing available props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

i want to outsouring the available props from my react table. 
I have search some websites, but i don't find anything about this case. 
The background of this case is, that i want to use this table more than once and i don't want to initialize the table again and again.

```
<ReactTable
  className='-striped -highlight mb-3'
  filterable
  data={this.state.data}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  sortable={true}
  multiSort={true}
  showPageJump={true}
  showPagination={false}
  showPageSizeOptions={true}
  collapseOnDataChange={true}
  collapseOnPageChange={true}
  collapseOnSortingChange={true}
  freezeWhenExpanded={true}
  resizable={false}
  pageSize={this.state.data.length}
  filtered={this.state.filtered}
  onFilteredChange={filtered => this.setState({ filtered })}
  columns={this.state.columns}
/>
```

From this code i want to outsource the follwing props:

- className
- multisort
- showPagination
- resizable
- etc.

Have you any idea, how i outsource this?

Regards MCW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Higher Order Components (HOCs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) -  a technique in React for reusing component logic. HOCs are not part of the React API, but instead a pattern that emerges from React’s compositional nature.

In this case, you want to create a HOC using some common `props`. One option to accomplish this is using the [ReCompose library](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose), with it's `withProps` method. Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { withProps } from "recompose";

import ReactTable from "react-table";

const CommonTable = withProps({
  className: '-striped -highlight mb-3',
  multisort: true,
  showPagination: false,
  resizable: false,
  etc: etc
})(ReactTable);
```

Also, it looks like there are some factors to be aware of when using ReactTable with HOC, outlined in the [docs](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/hoc-readme).

Here's an example:

```js
const { withProps } = Recompose;

const CommonTable = withProps({
  className: '-striped -highlight mb-3',
  multisort: true,
  showPagination: false,
  resizable: false
})(ReactTable.default);

const data = [
  {
    name: 'Tanner Linsley',
    age: 26,
    friend: {
      name: 'Jason Maurer',
      age: 23,
    }
  }
];

const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name' // String-based value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  }, {
    id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Friend Name',
    accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
    accessor: 'friend.age'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<CommonTable data={data} columns={columns} />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/recompose/0.26.0/Recompose.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How i use the const CommonTable? Must i set them in the react table or do this "withProps"?

Comment: `CommonTable` would be used like any other component, and would have the remaining `props` passed to it.

Comment: Thank you now it works, if i transform my code with your code.